# Android 11 FCM problem on locked screen (Kotlin)

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, lockscreen

I have an application. I extended the FirebaseMessagingServie. I added it into the manifest:

```
        <service
        android:name=".services.AutomentoFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I also overided the onMessageRecived method

```
 override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Topic message: " + remoteMessage.from)
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

    val powerIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)
    context?.sendBroadcast(powerIntent)

    wakeUpScreen()

    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
    )
    val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
    val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_rendeleseim_white_48)
        .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.notification!!.title)
        .setContentText(remoteMessage.notification!!.body)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setLights(Color.RED, 500, 500)
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    val channel = NotificationChannel(
        channelId,
        "Pushnotification",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH,
    ).apply {
        lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
    }
    
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    val notification = notificationBuilder.build()
    notification.flags = notification.flags or Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT
    notificationManager.notify(REQUEST_CODE, notification)
}

private fun wakeUpScreen() {
    val powerManager = getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    val isScreenOn: Boolean = powerManager.isInteractive
    if (!isScreenOn) {
        val wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock =
            (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
                newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MentoMano::WakelockTag").apply {
                    acquire(1000)
                }
            }
    }

    val pm = context!!.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    val isScreenOn2 = pm.isInteractive // check if screen is on

    if (!isScreenOn2) {
        val wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "myApp:notificationLock")
        wl.acquire(3000) //set your time in milliseconds
    }
}
```

I have the API key and I get the token. I can send a notification and the user get it when the app is runing, when it is in the background and it is not running.

**My problem:** the user doesn't get the notification when the screen is locked. I configured the phone. I can get pushnotification from the facebook Messenger when the phone is locked, but my **notification** arrives **only** when the user **opens the screen** or the screen is opened.

Comment: any solution yet?

Comment: Having same problem , let me know if you found the solution allready....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps somebodey I used this solution.

I kept the manifest as in the question

In inherited from FirebaseMessagingService

```
class MyMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService {
```

And I used this onMessageRecibed function

```
 override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Topic message: " + remoteMessage.from)
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

        val powerIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)
        context?.sendBroadcast(powerIntent)

        wakeUpScreen()

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            REQUEST_CODE,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
        val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
        val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_rendeleseim_white_48)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.notification!!.title)
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.notification!!.body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setLights(Color.RED, 500, 500)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            "Pushnotification",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH,
        ).apply {
            lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
        }

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        val notification = notificationBuilder.build()
        notification.flags = notification.flags or Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT
        notificationManager.notify(REQUEST_CODE, notification)
    }
```

This is the wakeUpScreen method

```
  private fun wakeUpScreen() {
        val powerManager = getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        val isScreenOn: Boolean = powerManager.isInteractive
        if (!isScreenOn) {
            val wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock =
                (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
                    newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MentoMano::WakelockTag").apply {
                        acquire(1000)
                    }
                }
        }

        val pm = baseContext.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        val isScreenOn2 = pm.isInteractive // check if screen is on

        if (!isScreenOn2) {
            val wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK or PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "myApp:notificationLock")
            wl.acquire(3000) //set your time in milliseconds
        }
    }
```